# Footer is showing middle of page

Tags: footer

1) My Footer isn't sticking to the bottom of my page:

*Below you will find my About Me page for a portfolio site. Struggling to get the footer to work. It appears to show in the middle of the page.*

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>About Me</title>
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.0/normalize.css">
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya|Kaushan+Script" rel="stylesheet">
    <div class="topnav">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
            <a href="work.html">Work</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
          </div>
  </head>
  <body>
    <body background="img/background.jpg">
    <header>
      About Me!
    </header>
    <div>
        <h1>XXXX (Yes, one name like <em>Prince</em>) is an aspiring Full-Stack Developer, Student, Teacher, Mom to XXX, XXX's Personal Assistant, Part Time Dry Comedian, and a Red Velvet Cupcake connoisseur in XXXX.
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>
        I am a <span style="color:#ff4652">career changer</span> who is currently attending <a href="https://nycda.com/"target="_blank">The New York Code and Design Academy</a> in XXX. My goal is to become an ongoing learner in the tech world; taking on as many new coding languages and projects as possible and become involved in the tech community. The desire and strategy for my work is built on creative thinking, problem solving, clean code, and functionality.
      </p>
        <table width="960" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="70">
            <tbody>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td width="240" height="240">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
                    </td>
                    <td width="240" height="240">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
                    </td>
                    <td width="240" height="240">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"</a>
      <footer>
        <a href="contact.html">Say Hi!</a>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

*This is part of my stylesheet for the footer below.*

**CSS:**

```
    #footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #ff4652;
  /* opacity: 0.5%; */


}
```

Comment: The bottom is related (even when absolute) to the parent element, which is your body element. If you do not have enough content to fill the whole screen, the "bottom" is where the content ends. You can use vh (viewport height) to force your footer into the 100vh, but if you have scrollable content or content that does not fit the screen height, it will fail the design. I would suggest using flexbox container, make the main div height 100vh or 100% and then fit the other content inside it, including the footer. OR use fixed footer+header and flebox-div between them to scale other objects.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. This is all so very new to me. I'll have to do a bit more research in order to execute your suggestions.

Comment: If you want to testdrive your non-flexbox/responsive style, you can make a main div like <div class="mainDiv"> which envelopes everything else inside the <body> and define .mainDiv {height: 100vh;}, in which case you can drop the footer into the actual "bottom" of the screen. Or even define the <html> and  <body> height as 100vh or 100% to see how your design reacts. (Also use min-height: 100% to be sure it fills the whole usable space).

Comment: Ahhhh, I see. That makes sense. Thank You!